# How to display and parse a stored variable of a viewer's date/time instead of server date/time in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, date, time

I want to make the end-user's actual date/time a variable in PHP verses the server's.  I've been playing with this PHP/Javascript concept even though I'm sure I'm way off.

The first I found on here, is a javascript method for using PHP to display the user's date/time verses the servers:

```
function hello() {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
var x = new Date()
document.write(x)
</script>';
}
ob_start();
hello();
$output = ob_get_clean();
print "--" . $output . "--";
```

But when I go and explode $output into an array via explode(" ", $output), instead of giving me the user's date/time (Sun Jan 21 2018 17:52:04 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)), it gives me:

```
type="text/javascript"> var
x
=
new
Date() document.write(x) Dec 31 1969Jan 21 2018
```

Any suggestions or does anyone have a (much) better method for obtaining a user's date/time and making it a variable that I can play with?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Of course when you explode the code it returns

```
type="text/javascript"> var
x
=
new
Date() document.write(x)
```

PHP is server side, Javascript is client side, you could create an ajax request to send your server their timezone then save it, for example:

Your php file, for this post I haven't escaped the post, but I suggest you do..

```
<?php

// For this post, but please escape it
echo $_POST['timezone'];
```

Front end, send to your php file.

```
<script>

(function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "myphp.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
        timezone: x
    }));
})();

</script>
```